# Cannot git push sub-folders

Tags: git, github

This might be dumb question to some of you, but I have moderately good knowledge of git tools and this is a very wierd thing happening with my project.

I am not working on github, but it is my research lab's GitLab server.

I am working on a project, which contains folder structure

```
$ ls
subproject1 subproject2 subproject3
```

**subproject1** was git cloned from another repository and then was modified. So does **subproject2**. **subproject3** is a completly new module that I am creating now.

Now I have created a new project in github remote and then git init that same location before pushing them to the new remote project.

I can see that I can only upload contents of the **subproject3** into the new repo. Contents of **subproject1** and **subproject2** never pushes into the project.

I tried everything, like deleted all hidden .git related files from the subproject folders, but nothing worked.

Can anyone guide me with this?

Comment: Are you using gits submodule feature? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: @MaxKeller i basically don't care to have those repository data as submodules anymore. Can I treat all the subprojects a integral part of one project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `git add .` ? This adds all modified and new (untracked) files in the current directory and all subdirectories to the staging area (a.k.a. the index), thus preparing them to be included in the next `git commit.`

Edit : Wrong command, was distracted.

Comment: This will be great if give some more describtion on what -rm does?

Comment: I can see your update. Sorry to say that didn't work at all.